# Most efficient way to calculate radial profile

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, optimization, scipy

I need to optimize this part of an image processing application.
It is basically the sum of the pixels binned by their distance from the central spot.

```
def radial_profile(data, center):
    y,x = np.indices((data.shape)) # first determine radii of all pixels
    r = np.sqrt((x-center[0])**2+(y-center[1])**2)
    ind = np.argsort(r.flat) # get sorted indices
    sr = r.flat[ind] # sorted radii
    sim = data.flat[ind] # image values sorted by radii
    ri = sr.astype(np.int32) # integer part of radii (bin size = 1)
    # determining distance between changes
    deltar = ri[1:] - ri[:-1] # assume all radii represented
    rind = np.where(deltar)[0] # location of changed radius
    nr = rind[1:] - rind[:-1] # number in radius bin
    csim = np.cumsum(sim, dtype=np.float64) # cumulative sum to figure out sums for each radii bin
    tbin = csim[rind[1:]] - csim[rind[:-1]] # sum for image values in radius bins
    radialprofile = tbin/nr # the answer
    return radialprofile

img = plt.imread('crop.tif', 0)
# center, radi = find_centroid(img)
center, radi = (509, 546), 55
rad = radial_profile(img, center)

plt.plot(rad[radi:])
plt.show()
```

Input image:
[image]

The radial profile: 
[image]

By extracting the peaks of the resulting plot, I can accurately find the radii of the outer rings, which is the end goal here.

Edit: For further reference I'll post my final solution of this. Using `cython` I got about a 15-20x speed up compared to the accepted answer.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.math cimport sqrt, ceil


DTYPE_IMG = np.uint8
ctypedef np.uint8_t DTYPE_IMG_t
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef void cython_radial_profile(DTYPE_IMG_t [:, :] img_view, DTYPE_t [:] r_profile_view, int xs, int ys, int x0, int y0) nogil:

    cdef int x, y, r, tmp

    for x in prange(xs):
        for y in range(ys):
            r =<int>(sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2))
            tmp = img_view[x, y]
            r_profile_view[r] +=  tmp 


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def radial_profile(np.ndarray img, int centerX, int centerY):


    cdef int xs, ys, r_max
    xs, ys = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

    cdef int topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight

    topLeft = <int> ceil(sqrt(centerX**2 + centerY**2))
    topRight = <int> ceil(sqrt((xs - centerX)**2 + (centerY)**2))
    botLeft = <int> ceil(sqrt(centerX**2 + (ys-centerY)**2))
    botRight = <int> ceil(sqrt((xs-centerX)**2 + (ys-centerY)**2))

    r_max = max(topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight)

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] r_profile = np.zeros([r_max], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef DTYPE_t [:] r_profile_view = r_profile
    cdef DTYPE_IMG_t [:, :] img_view = img

    with nogil:
        cython_radial_profile(img_view, r_profile_view, xs, ys, centerX, centerY)
    return r_profile
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like you could use [numpy.bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) here:

```
import numpy as np

def radial_profile(data, center):
    y, x = np.indices((data.shape))
    r = np.sqrt((x - center[0])**2 + (y - center[1])**2)
    r = r.astype(np.int)

    tbin = np.bincount(r.ravel(), data.ravel())
    nr = np.bincount(r.ravel())
    radialprofile = tbin / nr
    return radialprofile
```

Comment: Nice solution, about 3 times faster. I'll wait a bit before i accept this though, never know what people can come up with.

Comment: I used bincount and histogram in this implementation: https://github.com/keflavich/image_tools/blob/master/image_tools/radialprofile.py

Comment: Late to the party sorry but I have a question: Is `radialprofile = tbin / nr` not actually computing the **average** of the binned pixels ? OP said he wanted the **sum** of the binned pixels and hence shouldn't it be `radialprofile = tbin` ? (Hence we could also drop the `nr = np.bincount(r.ravel())` altogether). What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function in [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) that does just this: [`dip.RadialMean`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/math_projection.html#dip-RadialMean-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-dfloat--dip-String-CL-dip-FloatArray-CL). You can use it in a similar way to OP's `radial_profile` function:

```
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageReadTIFF('crop.tif')
# center, radi = find_centroid(img)
center, radi = (509, 546), 55
rad = dip.RadialMean(img, binSize=1, center=center)

rad[radi:].Show()
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm an author of the DIPlib library.</sub>

Comment: This solution run fast and is easily extendable to other statistics (min, max, sum).
It look like for the new version we should use `import diplib as dip`.

Comment: @ucsky Indeed, there is a `dip.RadialSum`, `dip.RadialMaximum` and `dip.RadialMinimum` as well. Updated the post to reflect new package name ("pydip" was already taken in PyPI).

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.histogram to add up all the pixels that appear in a given "ring" (range of values of r from the origin).  Each ring is one of the histogram bins. You choose the number of bins depending on how wide you want the rings to be.  (Here I found 3 pixel wide rings work well to make the plot not too noisy.)

```
def radial_profile(data, center):
    y,x = np.indices((data.shape)) # first determine radii of all pixels
    r = np.sqrt((x-center[0])**2+(y-center[1])**2)    

    # radius of the image.
    r_max = np.max(r)  

    ring_brightness, radius = np.histogram(r, weights=data, bins=r_max/3)
    plt.plot(radius[1:], ring_brightness)
    plt.show()
```

(By the way, if this really needs to be efficient, and there are a lot of images the same size, then everything before the call to np.histogram can be precomputed.)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from a numpy Enhancement Proposal I am working on:

```
pp.plot(*group_by(np.round(R, 5).flatten()).mean(data.flatten()))
```

The call to mean returns the unique values in R, and the mean of corresponding values in data over identical values in R.

So not quite the same as a histogram based solution; you don't have to remap to a new grid, which is nice if you want to fit a radial profile, without loss of information. Performance should be slightly better than your original solution. Also, standard deviations can be computed with the same efficiency.

Here is my latest draft [numpy group_by EP](http://pastebin.com/a3U8RkJJ); not a very concise answer as such, but a very general one. I hope we can all agree numpy needs something like np.group_by(keys).reduce(values); if you have any feedback, it would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Photutils for such kinds of tasks where you are required to get an azimuthally averaged radial profile.

```
from photutils.profiles import RadialProfile

img = plt.imread('crop.tif', 0)
center = (509, 546)
edge_radii = np.arange(55)
rp = RadialProfile(data, center, edge_radii)

rp.plot(label='Radial Profile')
```

Here's is the documentation for reference: https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/profiles.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).