# What is the best way to calculate radial average of the image with python?

Tags: python, image, algorithm, matplotlib, average

I have a square image, for example this one:

[image: Scipy coin demo image]

and I would like to calculate the 1D average of the image for each radius from the position (0,0). I have written some code to do so, but first of all it very slow even for small images, secondly I see that there are also some problems with the idea behind it. Code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
from skimage import data

image = data.coins()
image = image[:,0:303]
print(image.shape)

projection = {}
total_count = {}

for x_i,x in enumerate(image):
    for y_i,y in enumerate(x):
        if round(np.sqrt(x_i**2+y_i**2),1) not in projection:
            projection[round(np.sqrt(x_i**2+y_i**2),1)] = y
            total_count[round(np.sqrt(x_i**2+y_i**2),1)] = 1
        elif np.sqrt(round(np.sqrt(x_i**2+y_i**2),1)) in projection:
            projection[round(np.sqrt(x_i**2+y_i**2),1)] += y
            total_count[round(np.sqrt(x_i ** 2 + y_i ** 2), 1)] += 1

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(projection.items()))
x, y = [],[]

for k, v in od.items():
    x.append(k)
    y.append(v/total_count[k])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Radius from (0,0)')
plt.ylabel('Averaged pixel value')
plt.show()
```

The result of the code looks like this:

[image: Result of radius average of picture]

Has anyone have some clue how to improve my the script? I also don't know why in some cases there are some spikes which have very small average value. I would really appreciate some hints. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does *"calculate the 1D average of the image for each radius from the position (0,0)"* mean? Please spend some more words on the problem.

Comment: The idea is to calculate the average of pixel intensities in distance r from the beginning of the picture origin (0, 0). You can imagine this like: you take calipers and put one end in (0, 0) and with another one starting from very small gape you go from x0 to xn adding all intensities of pixels calipers goes though. You repeat this for all  Because from two axes x and y you will get only single dependence - radius from origin (sqrt(x^2 + y^2)). I would like to plot the dependence of average intensity in function of radius.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may filter the image by the radius by creating a matrix of radii `R`
 and calculating

```
image[(R >= r-.5) & (R < r+.5)].mean()
```

where `r` is the radius you are interested in.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data

# get some image
image = data.coins()
image = image[:,0:303]

# create array of radii
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(image.shape[1]),np.arange(image.shape[0]))
R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

# calculate the mean
f = lambda r : image[(R >= r-.5) & (R < r+.5)].mean()
r  = np.linspace(1,302,num=302)
mean = np.vectorize(f)(r)

# plot it
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r,mean)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Your algorithm works much faster than one proposed by @Ondro However, I was wondering if your approach would be also possible to use from image center and average not 90* but whole 360.

Comment: Sure, you would need to shift the origin to some other point, `R = np.sqrt((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2)`m where `(x0,y0)` would be the new center point.

Answer (score 2):

I have found also another, very elegant way of doing radial average posted by @Bi Rico [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242011/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-radial-profile):

```
def radial_profile(data, center):
    y, x = np.indices((data.shape))
    r = np.sqrt((x - center[0])**2 + (y - center[1])**2)
    r = r.astype(np.int)

    tbin = np.bincount(r.ravel(), data.ravel())
    nr = np.bincount(r.ravel())
    radialprofile = tbin / nr
    return radialprofile
```

It works quite well and what is most important is much more efficient than previously posted suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your spikes is rounding the Euclidean distance. Anyway for raster images would be more appropriate to use Manhattan or Chebyshev metric to group intensities. In my implementation, I created coordinate matrices which are arranged to the array of pixel coordinates. The actual distances are calculated using `cdist` function from `scipy.spatial.distance`. Inverse indices of unique distance values are used to index the image and calculate average intensities.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import data
from scipy.spatial import distance

image = data.coins()
image = image[:,0:303]
print(image.shape)

r, c = np.mgrid[0:image.shape[0], 0:image.shape[1]]
# coordinates of origin
O = [[0, 0]]
# 2D array of pixel coordinates
D = np.vstack((r.ravel(), c.ravel())).T

metric = 'cityblock' # or 'chebyshev'
# calculate distances
dst = distance.cdist(O, D, metric)
# group same distances
dst_u, indices, total_count  = np.unique(dst, return_inverse=True,
                                         return_counts=True)
# summed intensities for each unique distance
f_image = image.flatten()
proj_sum = [sum(f_image[indices == ix]) for ix, d in enumerate(dst_u)]
# calculatge averaged pixel values
projection = np.divide(proj_sum, total_count)

plt.plot(projection)
plt.xlabel('Distance[{}] from {}'.format(metric, O[0]))
plt.ylabel('Averaged pixel value')
plt.show()
```

Here is result for Manhattan metric
[image]
and here for Chebyshev metric,
[image]