# Cython code returning incorrect result datatype after running

Tags: python, types, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to implement some code I found on StackOverflow (credit to [Most efficient way to calculate radial profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242011/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-radial-profile)), and I'm finding a few issues in regards to the returned variable. The key datatype being worked on is a unsigned 16-bit integer; however, upon looking at the results, they appear to be a much higher bit than desired. Here is my setup code, and I'm compiling using Visual Studio build tools - would it be better to use GCC, and if so, can anybody point me towards tips on changing compilers?

The `setup.py` code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

ext_options = {"compiler_directives": {"profile": True}, "annotate": True}
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("radialAvgCython.pyx", **ext_options),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Thanks for your time!

EDIT 3: I think I may have found the problem, which lies within one of the functions in the Cythonic code, shown below:

```
cdef void cython_radial_profile(DTYPE_IMG_t [:, :] img_view, DTYPE_t [:] r_profile_view, int xs, int ys, int x0, int y0) nogil:

        cdef int x, y, r, tmp

        for x in prange(xs):
            for y in range(ys):
                r =<int>(sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2))
                tmp = img_view[x, y]

                r_profile_view[r] +=  tmp
```

I believe that, for every radius `r`, the value is being added to the previous value and no averaging is occuring; this is why the results tend to be much larger than expected. I'm going to try to find a way to average each r, but I think this may be the core problem with the results being substantially bigger than other simple azimuthal/radial average codes.

EDIT 2: Here is the code being used in `radialAvgCython.pyx`, as far as I can tell, the code is well-written, but results between this and a standard radial average vary wildly:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.math cimport sqrt, ceil


DTYPE_IMG = np.uint16
ctypedef np.uint16_t DTYPE_IMG_t
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef void cython_radial_profile(DTYPE_IMG_t [:, :] img_view, DTYPE_t [:] r_profile_view, int xs, int ys, int x0, int y0) nogil:

    cdef int x, y, r, tmp

    for x in prange(xs):
        for y in range(ys):
            r =<int>(sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2))
            tmp = img_view[x, y]

            r_profile_view[r] +=  tmp



@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def radial_profile(np.ndarray img, int centerX, int centerY):

    # Find and define image dimensions.
    cdef int xs, ys, r_max
    xs, ys = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

    # Find maximum radius based on defined center and image size.
    cdef int topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight

    topLeft = <int> ceil(sqrt(centerX**2 + centerY**2))
    topRight = <int> ceil(sqrt((xs - centerX)**2 + (centerY)**2))
    botLeft = <int> ceil(sqrt(centerX**2 + (ys-centerY)**2))
    botRight = <int> ceil(sqrt((xs-centerX)**2 + (ys-centerY)**2))

    r_max = max(topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight)

    # Create relevant variables and feed in, solve.
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] r_profile = np.zeros([r_max], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef DTYPE_t [:] r_profile_view = r_profile
    print(r_profile)
    cdef DTYPE_IMG_t [:, :] img_view = img

    with nogil:
        cython_radial_profile(img_view, r_profile_view, xs, ys, centerX, centerY)

    # Return radial profile.
    print(r_profile)
    return r_profile
```

EDIT: I should mention that I am using PyCharm as my IDE.

Comment: I think we need to see the contents of "radialAvgCython.pyx", preferably in a shortened [mre] version (or if the code is identical to some code from the linked question you need to tell us _which_ answer). Both MSVC and GCC support 16 bit integers so the compiler is not the issue

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded the example code; in fact, I think I found the problem (and to which, you are correct - the compiler would not be the problem).

Comment: It is still unclear for which input the results isn't what you expect (or what you expect). The example also doesn't look very minimal to me.

Comment: `r_profile_view`` is defined as a "standard int" (probably 32 bit, might be 64 bit). That's probably a sensible thing to do at least for the intermediate variable where it's being added up (since the number is likely to get quite big). What you do if you do a division afterwards is your choice.